# Generic WCF Data Service to expose a number of SQLite databases to Silverlight clients

Tags: silverlight, sqlite, wcf-data-services

Would it be possible to write a generic service to expose the contents of a number of SQLite databases, without knowing the structure of the databases at design-time?

I've been reading this series of [blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx) about custom data service providers; would this seem like a valid starting point?

If this is possible, would it be possible for us to be able to display the contents of a particular table in the SQLite database in a Silverlight client within a grid?

The purpose of this project is to allow our users to navigate the contents of the SQLite databases, in the same way as using a native query tool.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write a custom data service provider to do this. When wcf data services asks for metadata, you can look at the table schema and return whatever the structure of the table is. In fact, you can change the metadata if there are changes made to the underlying table also across requests.

Here's the link that should help you get started: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Pratik